# Omega theme stuck in mobile mode

Tags: theming

I'm fairly new to drupal and the omega theme, but I've gotten it to work on a couple virtual, test sites.  Unfortunately, now that I'm attempting to get it to work on a live site, it is stuck in mobile mode.  I can't get it to switch to any other, normal mode.  The "resize me" option is missing.  It still functions properly, but I don't exactly want users on a computer to see the mobile version of the website.  Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't figured out why this is happening for me in omega 4, omega 3 is ok.
Anyway I suggest you open firebug's console and see if any JavaScript library is failing to load (wrong file permission, file moved...).

Comment: Found it: If you are using omega-4, You should go to your sub-theme's configuration in layouts section make sure "Enable Layouts extension" is enabled.